# Writing Variables via QuickOPC in C# (Visual Studio)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms, server, opc

my project is about writing an OPC UA Client, to read and write variables on a Siemens PLC OPC UA Server. I'm using Visual Studio 2017 Enterprise and installed the Quick OPC Toolkit from OPClabs to get started and try to connect. To program the client, I'm using Windows Forms and C#. 
Connecting with the server and reading variables is working just fine, but writing them gives me a headache:

1.) Before I started programming on my own, I downloaded the OPC UA Sample Client from the OPC Foundation (if someone needs the download-link just ask, the download is hard to find). I connected to the server and could browse through the variables, but the write function was greyed out/not available.

2.) I started programming a very simple client, but also failed to write variables. Reading via Live Binding (http://opclabs.doc-that.com/files/onlinedocs/QuickOpc/2018.2/User%27s%20Guide%20and%20Reference-QuickOPC/webframe.html#Making%20a%20first%20OPC%20UA%20application%20using%20Live%20Binding.html) is working, also reading them by using easyUAClient.Read() works. I tried to write a variable with this code:

```
namespace ErsteOPCUAVerbindung{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var easyUAClient = new EasyUAClient();
        easyUAClient.WriteValue("opc.tcp://OpcUaClient:password@192.168.216.1:4840/", "nsu=SinumerikVarProvider;ns=2;s=/NC/_N_NC_TEA_ACX/$MN_PLC_CYCLIC_TIMEOUT", 1);

    }
}}
```

but I keep getting an exception:

OpcLabs.EasyOpc.UA.OperationModel.UAException: "An OPC-UA operation failure with error code -2144010240 (0x80350000) occurred, originating from 'OpcLabs.EasyOpcUA'. The inner OPC-UA service exception with service result 'BadAttributeIdInvalid' contains details about the problem."

{"OPC-UA service result - An error specific to OPC-UA service occurred.\r\n---- SERVICE RESULT ----\r\nStatusCode: {BadAttributeIdInvalid} = 0x80350000 (2150957056)\r\n"}

I have no idea what is causing this. I suspected, that maybe some kind of access restriction is the reason, but I can't find any hints about it in the documentations and besides I'm logged in as administrator anyway.

Has anyone an Idea? Thank you.

Comment: I represent OPC Labs and you will be welcome to use the Online Forums, http://www.opclabs.com/forum/index , to post questions related to the product. In this particular case, you might be writing to something that is made read-only by the server (although the error code should be different in that case). It is also possible that you need to authenticate to the server specifically (your Windows login does not "count") - this is done using the UserIdentity on the UAEndpointDescriptor you cann pass to WriteValue.

Comment: If you can read the tag but not write it then you probably did not configure the tag correctly.  Look at a property whose name resembles "write mask" or "access level".  Do note that a tag whose name resembles "plc cyclic timeout" would almost certainly be read-only, only the PLC controller could set that signal since it is the one that detects such an error condition.

Comment: @Hans Passant  I tried out diffrent Parameters (such as simple R paramerter) but it doesn't work either.

Comment: @ZbynekZ I'll try out the OPC Labs Forums next time, I just suspected, that the issue is more about the PLC than the Client. I took a step back and got an older version of the server and I'm using OPC UA Sample Client for now to make sure it's not my code causing the problems.

Comment: When I try to write a R-Parameter for example with the OPC UA Sample Client, I get the message: BadUserAccessDenied. So it has to be an issue with the useraccess, but I am logged in with  [SignAndEncrypt:Basic128Rsa15:Binary] and the admin login data created on the PLC. There is no clear reason why the user should not be able to write, or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

I have had one more look at your code, and the way you pass in the user name and password (in the URL itself) is definitely not correct. The way it is given now it is essentially ignored. It may or may not be the cause for the problem with the Write, but it definitely needs to be changed. The proper way of specifying the user name and password would be:

```
var client = new EasyUAClient();
var endpointDescriptor = new UAEndpointDescriptor("opc.tcp://192.168.216.1:4840/");
endpointDescriptor.UserIdentity = UserIdentity.CreateUserNameIdentity("OpcUaClient", "password");
client.WriteValue(endpointDescriptor, "nsu=SinumerikVarProvider;ns=2;s=/NC/_N_NC_TEA_ACX/$MN_PLC_CYCLIC_TIMEOUT", 1);
```

Comment: Thank you, as soon as it works with the OPC UA Sample Client, I'll try it out just as you said. The documentations about the methods are sometimes not very detailed, so I have a hard time to figure out what they want me to pass exactly.

Answer (score 0):

Update: I found a documentation, which explained, that the administrator does not have write rights by default and how you can change that. You need to call the methode GiveUserAccess and pass two Arguments, the Username and "SinuWriteAll" (the second one is kind of hidden). I'll try it now with C# and post my solution if it works.